# Add property to JS object

Tags: javascript, object

I know this may be a duplicate, but I have found a lot of questions that were similar to mine, but their answer did not answer mine. For example this page https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty did not contain the answer to my question, as far as I know.

This is what I have:

```js
var User = function() {
  this.name = '';
}

User.prototype.password = '';
// or
Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, 'password', {enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true});

console.log(new User()); // User {name: ""}
```

This of course adds password to the prototype of the object, but I'd like to add the password as a member after the constructor has been defined.
Is there a way to achieve this?

```js
var User = function() {
  this.name = '';
}

User.prototype.password = '';

console.log(new User()); // User {name: "", password: ""}
```

Comment: Don't put member data on the prototype. If you do all instances of that type will have the same value for that member.

Comment: So your question is how to make prototype properties appear in the console log? By the way, it should be `defineProperty(User.prototype, ...`. Anyway, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish by putting `password` on the prototype. Doesn't it need to be an instance property like `name` so it can be different for each user?

Comment: I think that is the problem: He wants his `User` function to have more instance properties *after* he has already defined the constructor. This is what I'm trying to solve in my answer.

Comment: Absolutely, @nils. Sorry for being unclear about this. The console log is not really part of the problem. I updated the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new Object with the `new` operator, it might prove to be difficult, if you can't modify the constructor anymore. As far as I know, the the constructor is the only place where can defined instance variables if you are using the `new` operator.

If you were to create objects with `Object.create`, [you can pass in further properties in the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which is similar to `Object.defineProperty`:

```
var User = function() {
  this.name = '';
}

User.prototype.xyz = ''; // Add whatever you need to your prototype

var o = Object.create(User.prototype, {
    'password': {enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true, value: ''}
});
User.call(o);
```

If you need to do this before Object creation, you could always wrap your original constructor in another function:

```
var User = function() {
  this.name = '';
}

User.prototype.xyz = ''; // Add whatever you need to your prototype

var originalUser = User;

var User = function() {
    this.password = '';
    originalUser.call(this);
}

User.prototype = originalUser.prototype;

var o = new User();
```

I personally find the `Object.create` version clearer and less error-prone (especially if you have multiple properties you want to add at different times).

Comment: This is very confused. You're defining a constructor, but then don't use it to create the object, instead using `Object.create`, then invoke the constructor as a regular function to act as a kind of initializer? Then in the second example, you're creating one version of User, then overwriting it with another one, then copying the prototype from one to the other--I don't get it at all.

Comment: I assumed a few things: 1. *He would probably want to use the constructor for other operations as well.* 2.  *He wants to add have more instance properties added to the object created using `new` than he has defined in his constructor. He does not want them in the prototype, otherwise his value will be overridden for all instances* – So I wanted to stick to his code as closely as possible. Does this make more sense? I'm certainly open to suggestions for improvement.

Comment: While both these solutions work, I have not yet decided on which I'm going to use. But thanks anyway!